# JPEG hardware Decode support in Android application

Tags: android, hardware, jpeg, decoder, skia

My Android app needs to decode large resolution based JPEG images on Android 2.2 phones(and above), currently I am using BitmapFactory.decodeStream API, i.e. SKIA library to decode the stream.

1) As per my knowledge SKIA uses software decoding, i.e. libJPEG to decode and doesnot use hardware decoders for the same. Correct me if I am wrong.

2) Is there any faster way to decode JPEG stream (other than SKIA) ?

3) Can "Media framework" be used to provide  JPEG hardware decoding? As per my observation it can be only used for video and audio.

Comment: Can libStagefrightw.so can be used to decode JPEG images ? Can we use it from Java app layer ?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skia supports hardware accelerated jpeg decoding. Stagefright doesnt handle jpeg decoding.