# Use hardware JPEG decoder in android using NDK or java

Tags: java, android, image, android-ndk, jpeg

I need to decode JPEG images using built in hardware jpeg decoder. I have tried libjpeg and libjpeg-turbo and to my understanding they are both software based decoders. I also tried `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` but it was also taking around 50ms to decode a 1024x768 image. Is there a way with which I can access the hardware jpeg decoder to decode  images efficiently.

Comment: How did you determine the 50ms time? Are you taking into account reading from 'disk' or network?

Comment: by using System.currentTimeMillis(); before and after BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray command. I have already read the file from disk into a bytearray. following is the java code.

long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(filecontent, 0, byteLength,options);

long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
 long diff = t2 - t1;

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351041/jpeg-hardware-decode-support-in-android-application

Comment: Another duplicate (no answers, though): *[Is it possible to use HARDWARE JPEG decoding on Android, and if so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039007/use-hardware-jpeg-decoder-in-android-using-ndk-or-java)*